# setting css specific to element in map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I am rendering a div multiple times by using map javascript function in my react application. I want to set css (width) of each element. Width will be element specific. I am rendering div like this

```
    {this.props.face_clicked_reducer.person_timeline.map((item, i) => (
             <div className= {`marker-item-${i}`} id="sele1"></div>
          ))
    }
```

className of each div is different. How can I set css of each element. For setting width I will be needing {item.time} reference.

I tried setting it in componentDidMount like this

```
this.props.face_clicked_reducer.person_timeline.map((item, i) => (
            $("<div className= {`marker-item-${i}`}></div>").css({
                "width": ((item.endTime - item.startTime) * (100/this.props.player_time_update_reducer.video_duration)) + '%',
                "left": ((item.endTime) * (100/this.props.player_time_update_reducer.video_duration)) + '%'
            })

    )).css('backgorund', 'red')
```

But it didn't work. I am not getting any errors in console.

Comment: Tip: **Please avoid using jquery with React**. React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It determines updates based on its own internal representation, and if the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets confused and has no way to recover. There are ways, so that you can use other plugins(like jqeury) but I personally don't like it or recommend it.

Comment: @RaghavGarg you meant "avoid" I think.

Comment: I agree, But a lot of libraries are just in jquery and to make webpage look good I end up using jquery.

Comment: @bennygenel, Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @RaghavGarg, while you cannot use jQuery in the fashion demonstrated in OP's code (because it returns a DOM element, not a ReactComponent), there are **many valid** use-cases of jQuery with React. Such as animations or inline-styling. Even certain DOM manipulations can be done without having "smelly code".

Comment: @Chris, animation or inline-styling seems like will not affect anything, agreed. But about DOM manipulation, I haven't faced such a case where jquery is a more suitable or required, so until then it's a no for me. :)

Comment: @RaghavGarg, there can be particular use-cases where this can be viable. For example an external library (eg. google maps, youtube api, etc) being loaded asynchronously where React only renders an empty `<div />` with an `id` attribute and then letting jQuery add children (perhaps event listeners, etc to them) to that div. All you'd have to do is make sure that component never gets re-rendered (you wouldn't want that anyway). I guess, all I'm saying is that you should be careful how you express that comment. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You are using the same `id` for each item in the array. IDs need to be unique.
2. The idea of css classes are to select multiple similar elements and not to have a unique class for each element.
3. If you re-arrange the items in the array, the css-class for the moved items will change.

---

That said, you could do apply an inline-styling instead:

```
this.props.face_clicked_reducer.person_timeline.map(
  (item, i) => <div style={{width: (50 * i) + "%", height:(20 * item.time) + "%"}}></div>
);
```

Alternatively:

```
this.props.face_clicked_reducer.person_timeline.map(
  (item, i) => {
    let s = {
      width: (50 * i) + "%",
      height: (20 * item.time) + "%"
    };
    return <div style={s}></div>;
  }
);
```

This prevents you from defining `person_timeline.length` number of classes in your css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style` prop for styling components.

```
{
    this.props.face_clicked_reducer.person_timeline.map((item, i) => {
        const style = {
            width: ((window.innerWidth * 0.2) * i),
            height: ((window.innerHeight * 0.2) * item.time)
        }
        return (<div className={`marker-item-${i}`} style={style}></div>)
    })
}
```

Comment: I want values in percent. I am not sure if style attribute can set dimentions in percent.

Comment: You can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` and calculate the desired percentage I think.